# distinct-values: The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(), but the supplied expression has item type xs:anyAtomicType

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have this XML file:

```
<collection>
    <journal name = "La Repubblica" issn = "1">
        <volume number = "1" date = "12/04/2022">
            <article doi = "AB23">
                <author orcid = "XY21">
                    <firstname>Marco</firstname>
                    <surname>Rossi</surname>
                    <affiliation>Affi</affiliation>
                </author>
                <author orcid = "XYZ">
                    <firstname>Simone</firstname>
                    <surname>Mambo</surname>
                </author>
                <title>Stop alle mascherine</title>
                <abstract>Da maggio si può dire basta alle mascherine</abstract>
                <keyword>COVID</keyword>
            </article>
            <article doi = "AB60">
                <author orcid = "XY21">
                    <firstname>Marco</firstname>
                    <surname>Rossi</surname>
                    <affiliation>Affi</affiliation>
                </author>
                <title>Un altro titolo</title>
                <abstract>Un altro abstract</abstract>
                <keyword>Titolo</keyword>
            </article>
        </volume>
    </journal>
</collection>
```

and this xQuery script:

```
<publications>
{
    for $au in distinct-values(doc("collection.xml")//author)
    return
    <author orcid = "{ $au/@orcid }">
       <firstname>{ $au/firstname/text() }</firstname>
    </author>
}
</publications>
```

Unfortunately this is giving me:

> XPTY0019  The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(), but the supplied
> expression {$ar} has item type xs:anyAtomicType

- How can I fix?

Comment: Which version of XQuery, which XQuery processor do you use? It looks as if XQuery 3 grouping would be a better choice.

Comment: @MartinHonnen This one: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm#ADXDK99995

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XQuery that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XQuery processor and its conformance with the XQuery standards: 1.0, 3.0, or 3.1.

Comment: Are you sure that's the XQuery processor you are using? The error message looks like a Saxon error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XQuery 3.0 is supported I think you want

```
<publications>
{
    for $au in doc("collection.xml")//author
    group by $author := $au
    return
    <author orcid = "{ $au[1]/@orcid }">
       <firstname>{ $au[1]/firstname/text() }</firstname>
    </author>
}
</publications>
```

[Online sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3Cpublications%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20%24au%20in%20%2F%2Fauthor%0A%20%20%20%20group%20by%20%24author%20%3A%3D%20%24au%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cauthor%20orcid%20%3D%20%22%7B%20%24au%5B1%5D%2F%40orcid%20%7D%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfirstname%3E%7B%20%24au%5B1%5D%2Ffirstname%2Ftext%28%29%20%7D%3C%2Ffirstname%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fauthor%3E%0A%7D%0A%3C%2Fpublications%3E%0A%0A&input=%3Ccollection%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cjournal%20name%20%3D%20%22La%20Repubblica%22%20issn%20%3D%20%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cvolume%20number%20%3D%20%221%22%20date%20%3D%20%2212%2F04%2F2022%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carticle%20doi%20%3D%20%22AB23%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cauthor%20orcid%20%3D%20%22XY21%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfirstname%3EMarco%3C%2Ffirstname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csurname%3ERossi%3C%2Fsurname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Caffiliation%3EAffi%3C%2Faffiliation%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fauthor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cauthor%20orcid%20%3D%20%22XYZ%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfirstname%3ESimone%3C%2Ffirstname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csurname%3EMambo%3C%2Fsurname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fauthor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EStop%20alle%20mascherine%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cabstract%3EDa%20maggio%20si%20pu%C3%B2%20dire%20basta%20alle%20mascherine%3C%2Fabstract%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ckeyword%3ECOVID%3C%2Fkeyword%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farticle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Carticle%20doi%20%3D%20%22AB60%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cauthor%20orcid%20%3D%20%22XY21%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cfirstname%3EMarco%3C%2Ffirstname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Csurname%3ERossi%3C%2Fsurname%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Caffiliation%3EAffi%3C%2Faffiliation%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fauthor%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EUn%20altro%20titolo%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cabstract%3EUn%20altro%20abstract%3C%2Fabstract%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ckeyword%3ETitolo%3C%2Fkeyword%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Farticle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fvolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fjournal%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fcollection%3E%0D%0A&code-type=XQuery&input-type=XML).

I don't know the XQuery processor of Oracle but the documentation you linked to in the comments links to XQuery 3.0 so based on that I would hope the above is supported.

It is not quite clear to me, which distinct value/grouping key you are looking for in `author`, given that your input sample has two or three child elements for that element. You can of course use e.g. `group by $first-name := $au/firstname, $last-name := $au/surname` instead.

If you don't have support for XQuery 3, you need to use e.g.

```
<publications>
{
    for $au in distinct-values(doc("collection.xml")//author)
    let $author := (doc("collection.xml)//author[. = $au])[1]
    return
    <author orcid = "{ $author/@orcid }">
       <firstname>{ $author/firstname/text() }</firstname>
    </author>
}
</publications>
```

Comment: Oracle XQuery Processor for Java
XDK now includes an **XQuery 1.0** processor for Java. This processor enables Java applications to query, transform, and update Extensible Markup Language (XML) directly in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: As I said, I don't know and can't tell, the section I read says "See Also" .. "http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/ for information about XQuery 3.0: An XML Query Language"

Comment: Just clarifying: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/release_changes.htm#ADXDK132

Comment: @MartinHonnen Any chance to achieve this in a cleaner way?

Comment: @tail, no idea what you consider a "cleaner" way. The group by in XQuery 3.0 is kind of a standard approach; if that is not supported (i.e. with only XQuery 1) then you need that mix of distinct-values (but which gives a sequence of atomic values) to then select the right nodes for each distinct value.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Anyway it doesn't work as expected (duplicates data inside a single element)

Comment: @tail, consider to edit your question and to show the expect result you want for your sample input. As I said, I don't have a clear idea what kind of distinct values or grouping keys you want from an `author` element having whitespace with variying child elements.